# How to load silverlight page to the mainPage ( user control )?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Writing my first silverlight application. 
I define the project as a 'silverlight application' and i created 4 pages ( navigation:Page ).

Now, i want to make them visible on the mainPage that is actually a simple userControl.

How can i do it? 
How can i move to the next page ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bust way is to use [Silverlight Navigation Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/1641/) is other example with source code from [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com).
[This](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/navigation-framework/) is video tutorial from [silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net)

Comment: in that case why do you need **navigation:Page**? If your pages are UserControls than you can add them(or one of them) to Grid for example or Canvas or some other control.

Comment: navigation:Page is part of the navigation framework, so you're already using it...